# Sphinx: list of modules of a subpackage

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

When I build my documentation, the left menu of the html documentation is something like:

```
main_package
 |
 |-- Subpackages
 |    |-- subpackage_1
 |    |-- subpackage_2
 |
 |-- Submodules
 |
 |-- Module contents
```

How can I add in this menu the list of the submodules? Example:

```
main_package
 |
 |-- Subpackages
 |    |-- subpackage_1
 |    |    |-- submodule_1a
 |    |    |-- submodule_1b
 |    |-- subpackage_2
 |         |-- submodule_2a
 |         |-- submodule_2b 
 |-- Submodules
 |
 |-- Module contents
```

Comment: This might be theme dependent. Which Sphinx theme are you using? It also might depend on the structure of your package and how you structure your toctree entries. Can you share both by editing your answer? In general, you can using the [`toctree` directive with `:maxdepth:` option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree).

Comment: @mauro: if you have a solution, please add it as an answer. The solution should not be in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using sphinx_rtd_theme and thanks to Steve Piercy's hint, the answer is that it is theme related. For this theme, in the conf.py file, it should be added `html_theme_options = {'navigation_depth': value}`.